# Current package for docker-compose?

Tags: apt, docker

Installing `docker` and `docker-compose` on ubuntu needs many steps. [[1]](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/) [[2]](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/)

E.g. for Arch you only need `pacman -S docker docker-compose`

- Why is the apt for `docker-compose` 'outdated'? (Version 1.24 vs. 1.21) How can I help to change this?
- Why use Docker another repository which I have to add?

My understanding about apt and how to maintain is a little bit poor. And I can't find something like in the the Arch package list, where you can read the package file. ([Example](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/community.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/docker-compose))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software) In Ubuntu 16.04 and later docker and composer can be installed from the default Ubuntu repositories. Open the terminal and type: `sudo apt install composer docker docker-compose`

Comment: You probably need to ask the people from docker. Installation -from- Ubuntu is the normal 3 or 4 lines: (possibly add keyserver,) add ppa for package, update system, install package

Comment: Tanks @karel and @Rinzwind
In the case of `docker-compose` the version is too old for me. 

Is for apt here a place to show the package file like for Arch? Or is there a way to contribute easy?

Comment: [Ubuntu Packages Search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) has the info online. The same information can be fetched from the terminal with `apt policy docker-compose` and `rmadison docker-compose`

Comment: Tanks, I have found on launchpad https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/docker-compose what I have searched.